# In JTable, color should be displayed in last column

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a GUI which has a `JComboBox` and a `JTable`.

- The `JComboBox` items are `Yes` and `No`.
- The `JTable` has 2 columns and 2 rows.
- If I select `Yes` in `JComboBox`, the second column should be displayed gray color and else white color.

How to do this? Is there any method to set the color without rendering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article [*How to Use Tables: Concepts: Editors and Renderers*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) shows how to use renderers. Just have your `JComboBox` action listener update the background color of your `DefaultTableCellRenderer` subclass.